# implement UP button by default (UP button icon)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

i know that if i want to implement UP button on the up-left-corner of the screen (i mean just its icon, not its whole implementation)  i have to put `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` in the `onCreate()`method of desired activity

but i want to know is it possible to appear UP button icon in its place without using `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`???

because in android studio i've done nothing but this icon is appeared

Comment: Does the activity has `android:parentActivityName` attribute in the manifest?

Comment: @hegazy : yes it has

Comment: That's it. I'll explain more in an answer.

Comment: @hegazy : tnx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide Up Navigation using one of these two methods:

1- **Specify the Parent Activity**

Note that `android:parentActivityName` is added on Android 4.1 (API level 16). So if your app supports Android 4.0 and lower, include the Support Library with your app and add a  element inside the . Then specify the parent activity as the value for `android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY`, matching the `android:parentActivityName` attribute.

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
    android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
    <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

2- Add Up Action

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

To have more info on this, check this link from the docs. http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html